# Method takes type to perform nhibernate queries?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I'm trying to create a method to perform nhiberate queries with different classes as parameters like:

```
 ...
 deleteFirst<ClientInfo>();
 deleteFirst<SellerInfo>();
 deleteFirst<AdministratorInfo>();
 ...

 public void deleteFirst<T>() where T: ClientInfo
 {
        var clients = Session.QueryOver<T>().Where(x => x.Id != 0).AndRestrictionOn(x => x.Entity).IsNotNull.List();
        Session.Delete(clients[0]);
 }
```

however here it only works with ClientInfo class.
all my clases extend BaseInfo class

Also baseclass doesn't have this Entity parameter, so if I use public void deleteFirst() where T: BaseInfo

(x => x.Entity) gives me an error(Can not resolve symbol entity)

Comment: You need to make a base class and extend your "info" classes from it. `public void deleteFirst<T>() where T: BaseInfo`. Your classes would look like this: `public class ClientInfo : BaseInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
public void deleteFirst<T, U>(Func<T, U> entityCondition) where T: BaseInfo
{
    var toDelete = Session.QueryOver<T>().Where(x => x.Id != 0)
        .AndRestrictionOn(entityCondition).IsNotNull.List();
    Session.Delete(toDelete[0]);
}
```

To Call

```
deleteFirst<ClientInfo, Entity>(x => x.Entity);
```

Although this will still fail if toDelete returns nothing

Comment: how should the method look like if lets say we added a check :   public void deleteFirst<T, U>(Func<T, U> entityCondition) where T : BaseError  
        {
            if (entityCondition != null)
            {
                var toDelete = Session.QueryOver<T>().Where(x => x.Id != 0).List();
              

                if (toDelete[0].Entity.parameter1 != null) // how to add this entityCondition here??
                {
                      Session.Delete((object) toDelete[0]);
                }

            }